# Remove extra empty strings?

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say I have a Python list of strings like so:

```
x = ["", "", "test", "", "", "not empty", "", "yes", ""]
```

How can I remove:

1. all leading empty strings
2. all trailing empty strings
3. all 'repeated' empty strings
   (i.e. reduce all internal sequences of empty space values to a single value)

`['test', '', 'not empty', '', 'yes']`

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Hey Chris. Could you tell us what criteria you're using to determine which empty strings to keep and which empty strings to throw out?

Comment: @nat5142 Sure, I want to remove all leading and trailing empty strings (that is, all strings before the first string with some content and all strings after the last string with some content). Additionally, for all of the empty strings in the middle of content strings, I want to reduce multiples to a single empty string (e.g.: ["", ""] to [""]).

Comment: This question is not too broad.  The problem statement is clear, and well defined.  The question is low effort, but the solution to that is to downvote, not close. Anyway, @ChristopherCostello look into using `groupby(x, key=bool)` to group the strings by whether or not they are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
content = list(x.next() for i, x in it.groupby(content))
b_l_rgx = r"^(\s+)?$"
if re.match(b_l_rgx, content[0]):
    del content[0]
if len(content) > 0 and re.match(b_l_rgx, content[-1]):
    del content[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with using [`dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) and [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby, dropwhile

def spaces(iterable):
    it = dropwhile(lambda x: not x, iterable)
    grby = groupby(it, key=bool)
    try:
        k, g = next(grby)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    yield from g
    for k, g in grby:
        if k:
            yield ''
            yield from g

x = ["", "", "test", "", "", "not empty", "", "yes", ""]
print(list(spaces(x)))
# ['test', '', 'not empty', '', 'yes']
```